# Take a message using DialogFlow

Tags: actions-on-google

Does anyone know if there's a helper intent for taking a message? I'm using the dialog flow SDK in Node and currently just using conv.ask() to ask for a message, but the time given for the user to dictate a message that way is to short and even a slight pause is taken to mean the end of the user input. I would like to emulate the way Google assistant takes messages for SMS, etc, for my app.  Even behavior similar to when you press the microphone input on the keyboard would be good, as that stays open while the user dictates.